# JavaScript React JSX: Looping Through Array of Objects And Setting Objects Horizontally Across Web Page

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, jsx

I currently have multiple divs each has its own content containing image, button, and text.

I loop through an array of objects to create these divs in react / redux JSX

The divs are showing up underneath each other and I want them to display horizontally instead.  Ideally I want three to a page, but as long as its horizontally displaying I'm satisfied.

This is a snippet of my JSX react code. It's inside a class component and it inherited the property houses.  Houses is an array of objects.

```
return (
    <div className="rows">
      <ul>
        {houses.map(house => (
          <li key={house.id}>
            <div className="row">

              <p>Location: {house.location}</p>
              <img src={house.imageUrl} height="150" width="320" />
              <p>FuelType: {robot.fuelType}</p>
              {/* delete button */}
              <button
                ... omitted button code
              </button>{" "}
              <button
                ... omitted button code
              </button>
            </div>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
```

I tried a bunch of things to make my divs go horizontal across the screen.  Including:

```
.rows .row {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

But no matter what I do the divs just show up underneath each other.

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You're applying the property to the parent's parent of the elements you're trying to horizontally span. Your class CSS should be applied to the `<ul>`.

```
<div>
   <ul className="rows">
```

Also, flexbox will horizontally span and is far easier to work with and reason

```
.rows .row {
  display: flex;
  // flex-wrap: wrap <- if needed
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Use cloumn count OR grid

one simple way use cloumn count: (for a 3 in a row)

```
.rows {
  display: block;
  column-count: 3;
}
.rows .row {
  break-inside: avoid;
}
```

you can also use flex or grid like:

```
.rows {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(360px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 10px;
  max-width: 900px;
}
```

and control the count of items in line with max-width